# Removes Special characters from the file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have out put like this:

```
'< Jan 20 Sep> This is the sample out put  
This is Sample 
>

'< Jan 21 Sep> This is the sample out put 
This is Known Errors 
 >
```

So i need to remove all > special character from the file. Only the line where one special character > is present needs to be removed. 
I would like to have below out put

```
'< Jan 20 Sep> This is the sample out put 
This is Sample 
'< Jan 21 Sep> This is the sample out put  
This is Known Errors
```

Comment: Please edit you post and use the appropriate formatting rules. That way it's much easier to help you.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes that's right and I tried it but sometimes I'm not sure of some characters are accidentally there or on purpose, especially if HTML tags are used  - as in this case. So I suggested that the author himself should edit his post.

Comment: Ah, right. That is a bit hard to interpret, yes. Also the example has the whole line removed (and also empty lines), not only the greater-than.

Answer (score 1):

If the '>' character appear in a single line as you show in the question, you can just:

```
grep -wv '>' thefile
```

Result:

```
'< Jan 20 Sep> This is the sample out put
This is Sample

'< Jan 21 Sep> This is the sample out put
This is Known Errors
```

Comment: Perhaps even with `grep -x` to remove only if the `>` is the only thing on the line. With `grep -w` lines with a `>` surrounded with spaces would also be removed.

Comment: Is exactly what i say.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the `>` characters at the beginning of each line and print the output to STDOUT. You will need to use the `-i` option to `sed` or redirect output if you want to write it to a file.

```
sed 's%^>%%' <filename>
```

e.g. you can test with this command

```
% sed 's%^>%%' <<'EOF'
'< Jan 20 Sep> This is the sample out put
This is Sample
>
EOF
```

result

```
'< Jan 20 Sep> This is the sample out put
This is Sample
```

Answer (score 0):

These commands should accomplish what you're looking for.

```
command | sed '/^ \?> \?$\|^$/d'
```

or

```
sed '/^ \?> \?$\|^$/d' file.txt
```

The regex reads out like this.

Anything that matches `/pattern/`

A line that contains a `>` with optional preceding or trailing space `^ \?> \?$`

or `\|`

Is blank `^$`

Delete it `d`